# Why does $g' \circ f$ = $\frac{dy}{du}$?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Online and in textbooks, the chain rule is usually explained like this. In the case where you're differentiating $f(g(x))$, they will define $y = f(u)$ and $u = g(x)$, then explain that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$, which is obviously true to me and very easy to understand.

The chain rule is $(g \circ f)' = (g' \circ f) \cdot f'$. It's pretty obvious that the factor $(g' ∘ f)$ is supposed to be equivalent to $\frac{dy}{du}$ above, but I don't understand how. Intuitively, it feels like $\frac{dy}{du}$ would be equivalent to $g'$ because it's rate at which $y$ is changing for each input unit of $u$.

Why does it take $u$'s rate of change into account?

Comment: I think there are some crucial typos; in the title, you meant $g'\circ f$, not $g'\circ f'$, right? Also in the body, it should be $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$. I think the main reason you are confusing is first you try to differentiate $f(g(x))$ but the formula  is for $(g\circ f)'$, which is $\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x))$.

Comment: https://mathinsight.org/chain_rule_idea#:~:text=The%20chain%20rule%20as%20multiplying,the%20functions%20f%20and%20g.

Answer (score 0):

From your definitions

$$y = f(u)$$
$$u = g(x)$$

then we have

$$\frac{dy}{du} = f'(u)$$
$$\frac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$$

The differential of $g$ (i.e. $\frac{du}{dx}$) is evaluated at $f(x)$, and is written as $(g'\circ f)$.